# Access New Version of Property/Method in Inherited Type

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have two classes. ClassA consumes ClassB. I want to be able to store a List of any ClassB objects (ie ClassB, ClassB both in the same list).

I have implemented this like so (simplified):

```
ClassB
{
    public object Thing {get; set;}
    AssignThing(object thing) {Thing = thing;}
}

ClassB<T> : ClassB
{ 
    ... 
}

ClassA
{
    public List<ClassB> list {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

However, I would like ClassB to be able to store Thing as its native type T, based on what T is, while still being able to access the T Thing and the T AssignThing from ClassA, from the list, without casting it to its respective ClassB. I initially tried the following implementation for ClassB:

```
ClassB<T> : ClassB
{
    public new T Thing {get; set;}
    AssignThing(T thing) {Thing = thing;}
}
```

However, when I access Thing from ClassA, it appears (via a quick watch) to be looking at `ClassB`'s version of Thing, rather than `ClassB<T>`'s, and `AssignThing` also uses `ClassB`'s version. Obviously, I can't override (instead of new) because they're different signatures.

It seems I'm a bit fuzzy on inheritance/polymorphism. Is what I'm trying to do possible in C#?

Comment: The `new` property is private, only that class can used that property. You can't really hide the property you inherited from the base class, so when other classes, or further derived classes try to access a property with that name, they only see the one you inherited from the base class. `new` is only useful in very specific scenarios, it is very rarely the solution you should use. If you tell us why you wanted to use it instead, someone might be able to tell you how to better do it than using `new`.

Comment: I was creating the example following the pattern of my code and was tired, and accidentally used private here instead of public. Thanks for pointing that out, but that's not the problem. I fixed the example.

Comment: Then create a [mcve].

Comment: What are you suggesting is missing from the code in the question? With the correction to public, the code is perfectly representative of the problem, and I believe my question is clear.

Comment: AssignThing cannot see the derived properties at all, that's what virtual is for, so since you didn't make it virtual, it will always refer to the property on its level.

Comment: So it sounds like, given that virtual/override require equivalent signatures, your answer is that it is not possible.

Comment: I still don't know what you want to do, all I know is what you're having problems with. I cannot tell you whether something is impossible without knowing what that something is. `virtual` is meant to handle the situation where you can override the implementation in a descendant type. If you don't use `virtual`, you cannot override the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the list of ClassB, not only ClassB.

```
class ClassB
{
    private object Thing {get; set;}
    public void AssignThing(object thing) {Thing = thing;}
}

class ClassB<T>:ClassB
{
    private T Thing { get; set; }
    public void AssignThing(T thing) { Thing = thing; }
}

class ClassA
{
    public List<ClassB<String>> list = new List<ClassB<String>>();
    public ClassA()
    {
        list.Add(new ClassB<String>());
        //Here you only can add ClassB<String>, not ClassB
    }
}
```

Another option would be naming them diferend. If you don't need them to have the same name, just call ClassB something like GenClassB

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach would then not allow me to keep ClassB<string> and ClassB<int> in the same list.